# Rsyslog load module with filter

Tags: linux, filter, module, redhat, rsyslog

I'm facing a problem right now :

I have a first machine (we will call it A), on which i've installed a Zabbix server, to monitor some other servers.

I would like to monitor the syslog daemon. And then i found : omsnmp, a rsyslog module which is able to send SNMP traps to my Zabbix machine A.

But, the problem is that, the syslog is too much important, and i don't want to send every message (information, warning, critical, ...)

I would like to send only critical messages present in syslog.

But, i don't have any parameter in the module omsnmp to specify the filter.

I would like to know, using http://www.rsyslog.com/doc/rsyslog%255Fconf%255Ffilter.html this documentation, if i'm able to do something like :

```
if $severity== 'critical' then {
   *.* action(type="omsnmp" parameters ??")  <- i load the module with parameters

}
```

Any help would be appreciated,

Waiting for any answers, or tracks to follow

Thanks,
sleakerz

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is the way for people who want to do the same task :

```
$ModLoad omsnmp
$actionsnmptransport udp
$actionsnmptarget 129.183.11.170
$actionsnmptargetport 162
$actionsnmpversion 1
$actionsnmpcommunity public
```

And now, use filters :

```
*.=alert :omsnmp:
*.=warning :omsnmp:
```

This will send SNMP traps only if the log is an alert or a warning, in fact, it will allow the module to then only these type of logs.

here are the filters available :

- emerg
- alert
- crit
- err
- warning
- notice
- info
- debug